# How computer distinguish an integer is signed or unsigned?

Tags: storage, unsigned, signed

Two's complements is set to make it easier for computer to compute the substraction of two numbers. But how computer distinguish an integer is signed integer or unsigned integer?
It's just 0 and 1 in its memory.

For exmaple,  `1111 1111` in the computer memory may represent number 255 but also can represent -1.

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signedness and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations

Comment: I don't ask how the signed number represented in the computer

Comment: did you read the links? they were posted because they are relevant to your question

Comment: Related: [So how does the computer interpret the result of unsigned/signed arithmetic if it is to be used again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32160186) / [distinguishes between signed and unsigned in machine code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51943912) / [How does ASM knows an arithmetic operation is signed or unsigned?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38194478) / [How assembly knows if register contains positive or negative number?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71803051)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Signed and unsigned use the same data, but different instructions.

The computer stores signed and unsigned integers as the same data. I.e. 255 and -1 are the same bits. However, you tell the compiler what type the variable has. If it is signed, the compiler uses signed operators for manipulating the variables (e.g. IDIV) and when unsigned, it uses another instruction (e.g. DIV). So the compiler makes a program which tells the CPU how to interpret the data.

Comment: It's worth noting that on most CPUs the instruction is different only in the case of multiplication (MUL/IMUL for IA32) and division (DIV/IDIV) ([instruction reference](http://www.posix.nl/linuxassembly/nasmdochtml/nasmdoca.html)). The nifty thing about 2's complement isn't really that it's easier to subtract, but that addition (ADD) doesn't care if the numbers are signed or unsigned. Because of this, subtraction is indeed easier, since to subtract one can easily calculate the 2's complement of the subtrahend and add it to the minuend.

Answer (score 6):

It does not distinguish them.
But with the complement, the computation is the same :

Below, `d` will be appended to decimal numbers, and `b` to binary numbers.
Computations will be on 8 bits integers.

`-1d + 1d = 1111 1111b + 1b = 1 0000 0000b`

But since we overflowed (yep, that's 8 `0`s and a `1` on a 8 bits integers), the result is equal to 0.

`-2d + 1d = 1111 1110b + 1b = 1111 1111b = -1d`

`-1d + 2d = 1111 1111b + 10b = 1 0000 0001b (this overflows) = 1b = 1d`

`-1d + -1d = 1111 1111b + 1111 1111b = 1 1111 1110b (this overflows) = 1111 1110b = -2d`

And if you consider these operations on unsigned (binary values will be unchanged) :

`255d + 1d = 1111 1111b + 1b = 1 0000 0000b (this overflows) = 0d`

`254d + 1d = 1111 1110b + 1b = 1111 1111b = 255d`

`255d + 2d = 1111 1111b + 10b = 1 0000 0001b (this overflows) = 1b = 1d`

`255d + 255d = 1111 1111b + 1111 1111b = 1 1111 1110b (this overflows) = 1111 1110b = 2d`

Unsigned versus signed is thus just a visual representation of unsigned, only used when displaying to a human :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let's understand it at the C programming level:

```c
int A; // Computer will allocate 32 bits in memory & name the memory block as A
unsigned int B; // Computer will allocate 32 bits in memory & name the memory block as B
```

```c
A = 5; // Computer will calculate its 2's complement and save 0000….000101 to memory
B = -5; // Computer will calculate its 2's complement and save 1111….111011 to memory
```

Format specifier = `%d`:
Stored number -> Calculate 2’s complement -> Convert to decimal -> Print

Format specifier = `%u`:
Stored number -> Convert to decimal -> Print

```c
printf(“A = %d”,A); // Computer will interpret the data as a signed number and calculate accordingly
printf(“B = %u”,B); // Computer will interpret the data as unsigned number
```

So in the computer, every data is stored in 2’s complement form only. But when it comes to printing it, the data is interpreted based on the format specifier/conversion operator given by the programmer.

If both `int` and `unsigned int` data types did the same work of *"simply creating a named memory block of 32 bits"* then, why do we need two different data types?

While printing data, the programmer will find it helpful to see the data type declaration and hence remember in which form this data is to be printed and by using which format specifier.