# So how does the computer interpret the result of unsigned/signed arithmetic if it is to be used again

Tags: cpu-architecture, integer-arithmetic

First of all its given that the computer/processor doesn't care whether the given number in binary is signed or unsigned number, depending on instructions it receives in op-code it performs signed or unsigned arithmetic, and in the given case it will interpret the number as signed or unsigned.

```
subu rd,rs,rt
```

rs stores 11100 rt has 01000.
Say it is supposed to do an unsigned arithmetic **11100 - 01000** the result would be obviously **10100** which is **20** in decimal notation, since we performed an unsigned arithmetic (subtraction). And this number is temporarily stored somewhere in the memory in a location address say "**rd**" to be used again.

Does this mean the number being stored at location rd can be used only for unsigned arithmetic in future.

**If yes:** please clarify the following.
How does the computer actually know that it has to apply unsigned arithmetic whenever it used the data in rd the next time.where is the data related to this (that rd can only use unsigned arithmetic) stored.

So would this mean the computer really cares if the number being stored in address **rd** is signed or unsigned which will be a contradiction to first statement.

**If no:** why can it be used for a different type of arithmetic? wont doing this create any complications.

Comment: The last bit in the number is used as a signal flag when you are using signed numbers, but if you are not using signed numbers that bit will be used for the value being stored itself, meaning that with signed numbers the range of values you can store is decreased,  Now for the second question, I believe it is a hint of the language itself to determine whether to use the last bit or not.

Comment: can u elaborate what you mean by signal flag 
@chromano

Comment: it is a bit reserved for determining if the number is positive or negative... so if it is 1, it is negative, if it is 0, then positive... Obviously, things get a bit more involved and I recommend you to read this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations

Comment: if there are 8 bits to store the unsigned number then same register can be used to store a signed number and if isnt any extra bit ie 9th bit
(which is supposedely the flag you speak of) 
to represent the format of the integer signed / unsignd then there is no way to distinguish the two representations by the computer.
and i have not heard of such flag any where!
@chromano

Comment: The flag is in the last bit (the 8th), that's why on signed integers you can only store values from -127 to 127.

Comment: say 11000001 is stored in 8 bit register 
what representation is it?
actually u cant say that it is unsigned / signed. the MSB which you are saying is the flag is actually the sign bit in signed form so we get range from -127 to 127                                                                                                                            
where as in unsigned form we can represent the numbers in only their magnitude ie positive they lie in between 0 to 255                                              the number of numbers you can represent by bth formats is the same @chromano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean the number being stored at location rd can be used only for unsigned arithmetic in future.

No.

> If no: why can it be used for a different type of arithmetic?

There is no information stored that determines whether the number is signed or unsigned, and it can be used for both signed and unsigned arithmetic in the future. The processor doesn't know anything about the history of the data in the register when it operates on it with a subsequent instruction, so the answer to *why?* is simply that there is nothing preventing it.

> Won't doing this create any complications?

I suppose it could if you are working in assembly language and choose to switch between unsigned and signed arithmetic without a reason. Usually people work in compiled languages like C, in which case each number has a type and is either signed or unsigned, and at compile time the language will generate machine code that uses arithmetic corresponding to the type of the number.