# Compare unsigned with literal

Tags: c, gcc, x86

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893232/how-computer-distinguish-an-integer-is-signed-or-unsigned), that there are different arithmetical assembly instructions for signed operations. However consider code:

```
unsigned char a = 0xff;
if(a == 0xff){
    // do something
}
```

I remember in collage I made such code and the `if` condition was never true, but it was on AVR. I have seen similar thing in my work, so I typed that to the godbolt and for x86 it shows:

```
mov     BYTE PTR [rbp-1], -1
cmp     BYTE PTR [rbp-1], -1
jne     .L2
```

which is disturbing, because it shows, that unsigned modifier is ignored. Is it regulated by standard and gcc just simplified for optimalization purposes and actually converted `0xff` to unsigned?

EDIT: There was some confusion about my original problem (that's on me I didn't mention my example was meant for 8bit processor) so here's an alternative:

```
int main(){
    unsigned int a = 0xffffffff;
    if(a == -1)
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

translates to:

```
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], -1
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], -1
        jne     .L2
        mov     eax, 0
        jmp     .L3
.L2:
        mov     eax, 1
.L3:
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

which (if I understand correctly) means, that 2^32-1 actually equals -1.

Comment: The unsigned modifier is not ignored. Which instructions would you expect instead of these?

Comment: After `unsigned char a = 0xff;`, the value of `a` is 255. The value of the literal `0xff` is also 255. Even if there is a conversion, when 255 is converted to `unsigned char` or to `int` or to `unsigned int`, the value is still 255. So the compiler would compare 255 to 255. What do you think should happen differently?

Comment: what you did in **college** was probably using `char` which was a signed type.

Comment: I expected to see:
```movzx eax, BYTE PTR [rbp-1]
cmp eax, -1```

Comment: But `0xff` isn't `(int)-1`.  It's a small positive integer.  So `cmp eax, -1` would implement the C logic; it's the wrong constant.  But yes, a `movzx` load would explicitly implement the C integer promotion rules of a value-preserving widening of that operand to `==` to `int`, matching the type of `0xff` (which as a numeric literal defaults to int already, no promotion needed).  Note that even on an 8-bit processor, `int` is guaranteed by ISO C to be at least 16 bits wide, and `0xff` is comfortably below INT_MAX.  We only get a byte-compare with `-1` after optimizing away widening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I expected to see: `movzx eax, BYTE PTR [rbp-1]` / `cmp eax, -1`

But `0xff` isn't `(int)-1`.  It's a small positive integer.  So `cmp eax, -1` wouldn't implement the C logic; it's the wrong constant.

Yes, a `movzx` load would explicitly implement the C integer promotion rules of a value-preserving widening of that operand to `==` to `int` (the "usual arithmetic conversions").  This gives you an `int` matching the type of `0xff` (which as a numeric literal defaults to `int` already, no promotion needed in the C abstract machine).  So the `movzx` part is a valid part of naively implementing the C abstract machine rules.

See [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules) and  https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion.  Note that in the C abstract machine, basically everything you can do with a narrow type promotes it to `int` before the operation, even something like unary `-` negation.  But compilers are can usually optimize back down to the actual operand-size of the original variable for an operation that ultimately has the same result.

Note that even on an 8-bit processor, `int` is guaranteed by ISO C to be at least 16 bits wide, and `0xff` is comfortably below INT_MAX.  We only get a byte-compare with `-1` after optimizing away widening.

---

> which (if I understand correctly) means, that 2^32-1 actually equals -1.

Yes, x86 like all modern ISAs uses 2's complement integers.  ISO C allows 2's complement, 1's complement, or sign/magnitude.

(Fun fact: C++20 finally dropped the others, specifying only 2's complement.  Signed overflow is still undefined behaviour, but that's a separate issue...  Modern optimizing C and C++ implementations are very far from portable assembly language.)

Answer (score 3):

There are *not* different instructions for most operations for signed and unsigned integers in x86. The representation of -1 in 8 bits is 0xff. So the instructions shown are *exactly* the same as if the constant were written 0xff.

Comment: P.S.  It’s better to not look at unoptimized compiler output. It’s pretty much crap code.

Comment: Ok, so char is an example, because at collage I was working on 8bit processor, but what if there will be -1 (written 0xffff..) that takes whole memory cell? I was asking if such literal will be interpreted as -1 or 2^n-1? So i.e. if my condition will be ever true.